# How to fix 'Unknown method 'login' Angular' - in login/register page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, hybrid-mobile-app

Im trying to learn how to create a hybrid app so I can deploy on IOS and Android at the same time. I started by making login page and register, but right at the start I got stuck while trying to make the simplest interface and giving it a click listener. On "(click)="login()"" it gives me an error stating:

> Unknown method'login' Angular

I've tried going through some threads, but none of them help. I've also tried remaking the whole project in order to see if I maybe didn't go wrong in one of my steps during the installation. I've tried updating Angular and Ionic.

```
<ion-header>
<ion-toolbar>
<ion-title>Login</ion-title>
</ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
<ion-list>

<ion-item>
<ion-label position="floating">Username</ion-label>
<ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="username"></ion-input>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
<ion-label position="floating">Password</ion-label>
<ion-input type="password" [(ngModel)]="password"></ion-input>
</ion-item>

</ion-list>

<ion-button fill="solid" expand="block" color="dark" 
(click)="login()">Login</ion-button>
</ion-content>
```

As for expected results, I guess it just needs to show up without an error.

As I've said, it underlines the login click listener and gives the error above.

Then password and username identifiers are also underlined, saying "Identifier 'username' is not defined. The component declaration, template variable declarations, and element references do not contain such a member Angular"

In the once I serve my code to Ionic lab and open up the console I get 4 warnings as follows

> Native: tried calling SplashScreen.hide, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator
>   cordovaWarn @ common.js:290

It also mentions "call enableprodmode() to enable the production mode".

Comment: where did you define login method

Comment: Ehhhm im following a tutorial on youtube. The guy started of with a new blank ionic project, and these are pretty much the only lines of code that he has changed. 
And if i am correct i didnt define login method. Could you probably show me how to?

Comment: you have to write login function inside your component.ts file

Comment: could you possibly give me a code snippet? 

Since im following the tutorial on youtube where the guy does not put a login function in the components.ts file

Comment: can you provide the tutorial link?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q8zcieAWn3g&list=PLYxzS__5yYQnpK36-GJjm7IEAuHR7IExa&index=3

Hes got the source code on github the final version with firebase auth etc.

Comment: Maybe itll be worth noticing that im Using a windows machine, and the guy is using a mac. I also see that he does not need to use semicolons which is super weird in my opinion.

Comment: this was his code link https://github.com/codedamn/social-media-app-ionic4

Comment: i already saw the code. But i would like to do it myself in order to learn something. Thats why i turned to stackoverflow

Comment: login() is defined in [login.page.ts](https://github.com/codedamn/social-media-app-ionic4/blob/7a4bf7b33a7f71202b0f0640a31f4e4e27d7ce0e/src/app/login/login.page.ts#L20), does your "login.page.ts" look **exactly** like that? The the component that loads that page/view does not have `login()`, then you will continue having that error.